# Summernote Rich-text editor: minHeight and maxHeight options have no effect

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, richtextbox, rich-text-editor, summernote

I am using [Summernote](http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/) as a rich-text editor, however the `minHeight` and `maxHeight` initialization options have seemingly no effect?  (It works fine with the `height` option.)

I searched for other posts but couldn't find one with exactly the same problem.  Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id='summernote_editor' name='summernote_editor' class='summernote'></textarea>
```

**jQUery:**

```
$(function() {
    $('.summernote').summernote( {
        minHeight: 200         // using maxHeight here instead, or both, has no effect either
    });
});
```

I am using the latest version of `Summernote`, and it runs ok in other respects while using `jQuery 1.11.1`, `Bootstrap 3.0.1`, and `font awesome 4.0.3`.  Tested in `Chrome` and `IE10` browsers.

If anybody knows a fix for this issue, please let me know.

Comment: Another annoying issue is that the necessary bootstrap styles are overriding many of my other styles and consequently breaks my design.  I don't want to override styles using `!important` because of maintainability issues.  I think Summernote might not be for me - pity.

Comment: I'm shocked that this still seems to be a problem. None of these worked for me: `'minHeight' => 200`, `'min-height' => 200`, `'minHeight' => '200px'`, `'min-height' => '200px'` even when specifying beforehand `'height' => null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is a small bug, I needed to modify the core library to get this working. See the code below where I added the `else if`

```
if (options.height) {
    $editable.height(options.height);
} else if(options.maxHeight){ 
    $editable.css('max-height', options.maxHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this via CSS instead of JavaScript:

```
.my_summernote + .note-editor > .note-editable{
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

(Then set the `textarea` to have class "my_summernote".)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the minimum height (e.g. 250px) when the control opens.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#summernote').summernote();
  $('div.note-editable').css({ 'min-height': 250 + 'px'});
});
```